# How to get MVC Action parameter from AuthorizationContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I am currently trying to write a custom authentication filter and I need to access the dto that is being passed as a parameter to the action in my filter. Lets say I have an action like this

```
[AuthenticateProfile]
public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfileDTO profileDto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do crazy stuff
        }

        return something....
    }
```

I need to do my authentication based on some of the properties that are inside profiledto object.

I want to know how I can get this object inside my filter from AuthorizationContext.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I did it:

```
var parameters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
var values = parameters.Select(s => new 
             {
                 Name = s.ParameterName,
                 Value = filterContext.HttpContext.Request[s.ParameterName]
             });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your logic is happening in `OnActionExecuting` (meaning before the actual controller action is run), then one way of doing this (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616815/115049)) would be:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
      return;

   var profileDto = filterContext.ActionParameters.SingleOrDefault(ap => ap.Key == "profileDto").Value;
   if (profileDto != null)
   {
      // do something with profileDto
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I failed to mention that I need this inside my OnAuthorization method where I have access to AuthorizationContext and I believe I can not access action parameters from that context. Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to access the raw route values then, as AuthorizationFilters run before any model binding has taken place.

Comment: Thanks, Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core

```
var parameters =
      filterContext
        .ActionDescriptor
        .Parameters
        .Select(s => new
        {
           Name = s.Name,
           Value = context.HttpContext.Request.Query[s.Name]
        });
```

*extension*

```
public static StringValues? Parameter(this AuthorizationFilterContext context, string name)
{
     var parameter = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Name == name);
    if (parameter == null) return null;
     return context.HttpContext.Request.Query[parameter.Name];
}
```

*use*

```
 var parameter = context.Parameter("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for you to try out:

```
public class AuthenticateProfileAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        // Looping through named parameters
        foreach (string name in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys) {
            var value = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[name];
            // do something with the iteration
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + value);
        }

        // Looping through un-named parameters a.k.a route parameters
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in filterContext.RouteData.Values) {
            var name = parameter.Key;
            var value = parameter.Value;
            // do something with the iteration
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + value);
        }

        // Get single named parameter
        string parameter = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["parameter"];

        // Get single route parameter
        parameter = filterContext.RouteData.Values["parameter"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Using MVC 5.